# MVC - There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'UserType'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmWHy.png)

Server Error in '/' Application.
The ViewData item that has the key 'UserType' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'.

```html
class view

<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserType, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-2">
            @Html.DropDownList("UserType", ViewBag.UserTypelist as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

```html
class model
public class RegisterViewModel
        {
        
        [Required]
        [DisplayName("نوع الحساب")]
        public string UserTypelist { get; set; }
        
        }
```

```html
class controller

[AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Register()
        {
            //to show drop down list
            ViewBag.UserTypelist = new SelectList(db.Roles, "Name", "Name");
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Register
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ViewBag.UserTypelist = new SelectList(db.Roles,"Name", "Name");
                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.Email, UserType= model.UserTypelist };
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);
                    
                    // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                    // Send an email with this link
                    // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                    // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                    // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");
                    await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id,model.UserTypelist);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                AddErrors(result);
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

how to solve this please any who help me to solve this problem

Comment: Your screenshot shows you are casting `ViewBag.UserType` to `SelectList`. The code you posted as text is using `ViewBag.UserTypelist` instead. Apparently you have both and are not using the right one, and the code you posted is not in fact code you are running.

Comment: hello -GSerg i edited my image description see again please image description and The current image description shows the state of the code below

Comment: You probably want to make UserTypeList and IEnumerable of some type.  Maybe IEnumerable<string>.

Comment: You do not assign the value of `ViewBag.UserTypelist` in the POST method before you return the view (the only place you assign it is when `ModelState` is valid which is pointless because you then redirect

Comment: And your `public string UserTypelist { get; set; }` property makes no sense - I assume you mean that is `public string UserType { get; set; }` since that is the property you are binding to.

Answer (score 0):

Normally we avoid to use the key of ViewBag which we have in the view model or model to which our view in strongly typed. What you can do is instead use different key like `UserTypeSelectList` as key :

```
ViewBag.UserTypeSelectList = new SelectList(db.Roles, "Name", "Name");
```

and now in view try like:

```
@Html.DropDownList("UserType", ViewBag.UserTypeSelectList as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

or another way is to use the same key which you have in the view as name of `DropDownList` like:

```
ViewBag.UserType = new SelectList(db.Roles, "Name", "Name");
```

and then in View it will autmatically populate the dorpdown using the information from ViewBag against that name :

```
@Html.DropDownList("UserType", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Hope it helps.